# Styling Jquery UI tabs navigation

Tags: css, jquery-ui-tabs

Does anyone know how to do this in CSS?

[Navigation tab image](http://screencast.com/t/FvW2Q8lwu)

This is for the navigation tabs for jQuery UI tabs. I can't get the border-radius to work. Currently, I can do this shape but with no radius on top-left and top-right.

```
    border-right: 47px solid transparent;   
    border-bottom: 35px solid #415049;
    border-left: 15px solid transparent;    
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0px;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0px;   
    height: 0;  
    background:none;
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You're looking at an image background, or the left shape of the tab as a background image in a ::before and the right shap of the tab in a ::after

Comment: Check my answer i already implemented this on my recent project :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your answer

If you want shape like this use :before :after

I have created fiddle for you

Here is code

**HTML**

```
<div><span></span></div>
```

**CSS**

```
div > span {
    background-color: #333333;
    border-radius: 6px;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 50px;
    width: 200px;
}

div {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 43px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0 106px 0 46px;
    position: relative;
    width:
}
div:after {
    background-color: #333333;
    border-radius: 10px;
    content: " ";
    height: 100px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 44px;
    top: 15px;
    transform: rotate(30deg);
    width: 100px;
}
div:before {
    background-color: #333333;
    border-radius: 8px;
    content: " ";
    height: 50px;
    left: 39px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 6px;
    transform: rotate(15deg);
    width: 50px;
}
```

Here is fiddle for you http://jsfiddle.net/96sv3/2/

Hope this helps you :)

Comment: AlwaYz Welcome Dude :)

Comment: I've been trying to tweak this as I just started to tackle this task for my project. Anyway, is there anyway to attain this without pushing the other menus far right? It seems that the padding is pushing it away. Container is 900 px width and there should be three navigations of these shapes. Any tips?

Comment: You're a life saver dude.. Thanks a lot... I just have to remove the width for the span because it got text though... but overall you're solution works perfectly. Thanks again. Long live.

Comment: ThnX Man :) Nd also AlwaYZ Welcome Again :)

Answer (score 0):

Oh, man! Been there done that.

You can use background images for the tabs and tab states.

Or; try border radius defining left, right, top, bottom.

***EG.***

```
 border-bottom-left-radius:2em;
```

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_border-bottom-left-radius